# unsatisfiedLinkerError even after installing the required libraries

Tags: java

I am using jpcap library to read network traffic and getting exception while executing the following code:

```
NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
```

Following is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[Ljpcap/NetworkInterface; at
>   jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList(Native Method) at
>   nav.weka.first.JcapTest.main(JcapTest.java:16)

I already have installed jpcap and winpcap and also checked that their dll are present in system and system32

Comment: It maybe because of library's mismatch(32/64 bit)! Which JRE are you using?

Comment: Did you invoke this `System.loadLibrary("JpcapCaptor.dll");` in your code?

Comment: yes i did invoke after your comment and i dont think so that invoking was needed as i already imported the lib. and added the jar to my projects

Comment: the problem disappeared when i used eclipse neon instead of eclipse helios